# Laravel 5.2 and ajax Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Hi i m trying to make To do list application with laravel and ajax the probleme is if i tr to add,edit, delete a Task i get a  ***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500***
[image]
**But when i click on the link with the error the returned data appears in json format**

[image]
View :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Laravel Ajax CRUD Example</title>

    <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-narrow">
        <h2>Laravel Ajax ToDo App</h2>
        <button id="btn-add" name="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Add New Task</button>
        <div>

            <!-- Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Task</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Date Created</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tasks-list" name="tasks-list">
                    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
                    <tr id="task{{$task->id}}">
                        <td>{{$task->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$task->task}}</td>
                        <td>{{$task->description}}</td>
                        <td>{{$task->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="{{$task->id}}">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-task" value="{{$task->id}}">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- End of Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <!-- Modal (Pop up when detail button clicked) -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Task Editor</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form id="frmTasks" name="frmTasks" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">

                                <div class="form-group error">
                                    <label for="inputTask" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Task</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="task" name="task" placeholder="Task" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="add">Save changes</button>
                            <input type="hidden" id="task_id" name="task_id" value="0">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/ajax-crud.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then i have a JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = "/ajax-crud/public/tasks";

    //display modal form for task editing
    $('.open-modal').click(function(){
        var task_id = $(this).val();

        $.get(url + '/' + task_id, function (data) {
            //success data
            console.log(data);
            $('#task_id').val(data.id);
            $('#task').val(data.task);
            $('#description').val(data.description);
            $('#btn-save').val("update");

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }) 
    });

    //display modal form for creating new task
    $('#btn-add').click(function(){
        $('#btn-save').val("add");
        $('#frmTasks').trigger("reset");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

    //delete task and remove it from list
    $('.delete-task').click(function(){
        var task_id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({

            type: "DELETE",
            url: url + '/' + task_id,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                $("#task" + task_id).remove();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });

    //create new task / update existing task
    $("#btn-save").click(function (e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })

        e.preventDefault(); 

        var formData = {
            task: $('#task').val(),
            description: $('#description').val(),
        }

        //used to determine the http verb to use [add=POST], [update=PUT]
        var state = $('#btn-save').val();

        var type = "POST"; //for creating new resource
        var task_id = $('#task_id').val();;
        var my_url = url;

        if (state == "update"){
            type = "PUT"; //for updating existing resource
            my_url += '/' + task_id;
        }

        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({

            type: type,
            url: my_url,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                var task = '<tr id="task' + data.id + '"><td>' + data.id + '</td><td>' + data.task + '</td><td>' + data.description + '</td><td>' + data.created_at + '</td>';
                task += '<td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="' + data.id + '">Edit</button>';
                task += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-task" value="' + data.id + '">Delete</button></td></tr>';

                if (state == "add"){ //if user added a new record
                    $('#tasks-list').append(task);
                }else{ //if user updated an existing record

                    $("#task" + task_id).replaceWith( task );
                }

                $('#frmTasks').trigger("reset");

                $('#myModal').modal('hide')
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And route

```
Route::get('/tasks/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::post('/tasks',function(Request $request){
    $task = Task::create($request->all());

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::put('/tasks/{task_id?}',function(Request $request,$task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);

    $task->task = $request->task;
    $task->description = $request->description;

    $task->save();

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::delete('/tasks/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::destroy($task_id);

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    $tasks = Task::all();

    return View::make('welcome')->with('tasks',$tasks);
});
```

Comment: you dont have any route registered for this url '/ajax-crud/public/tasks', declare it. then the 500 error will go

Comment: it s the second route post::......

Comment: No bro. You can't declare it like that. You need to pass the url given in ajax as the route parameter.

Comment: Like Route::post(/ajax-crud/public/tasks and the. Point to a controller and its function where you will do something with the ajax data

Comment: when i add /ajax-crud/public/ tom my routes i get Methode not allowed

Comment: show the route how you have added it

Comment: @Exprator i followed this tutorial [link](https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-ajax-tutorial) i don't think that the problem with routes because it works form get and delete methode the problem is with post and put method

Answer (score 0):

the problem was  with

```
Route::post('/tasks',function(Request $request){
    $task = Task::create($request::all());

    return Response::json($task);
});

Route::put('/tasks/{task_id?}',function(Request $request,$task_id){
    $task = Task::find($task_id);
```

So i resolve the probleme by adding `\Illuminate\Http\Request`  as type of $request