# Laravel 5.5 csrf error with Datatable service

Tags: php, laravel

I create datatable with [**Laravel** datatable service](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/service). This datatable has filters, when i apply filters and use *post* to find results return

> The page has expired due to inactivity. 
>   Please refresh and try again.

The debugbar return

> VerifyCsrfToken.php#70

In console

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419
>   (unknown status)

My route is

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'visitas/listado', 'VisitasController@listado');
```

So ¿why can´t I use *post* to search in filters? ¿Why return VerifyCsrfToken.php#70?

Comment: Have you added `crsf_field()` to your form ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937363/laravel-5-2-and-ajax-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status

Comment: This might help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/disabling-csrf-for-a-specific-route-in-laravel-5

Comment: I have crsf_field() in my form and doesn´t work. In other hand i prefer to not disable csrf.

Answer (score 0):

This may be problem of token which is expected. Please insert this in javascript file or layout template.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: I have your code in de main.js and the error continue. ¿Maybe the error is this return  ' return $dataTable->render('moduloVisitas.visitas.listado');' ?

Comment: It should be called before calling datatable.